# How to have scrollbar start at a certain position on page load in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a very wide image as my background, let's say 4000px.

I would like to have my React page load right in the middle of the image, at 2000px.

How do I get my page to start automatically at 2000px width upon page load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dynamic method of achieving this would be to use a ref. We can create a callback function which accepts a ref, which we assign to your image container. This way we can react to the ref as soon as it is created.

The function will calculated the the scroll position dynamically and the scrollLeft set explicitly. The function might look like this

```
  const refAssignCallback = (ref) => {
    if (ref) {
      //ref available = mounted.
      var element = ref;
      var scrollWidth = element.scrollWidth;
      var clientWidth = element.getBoundingClientRect().width;

      //explicitly set the scrollTop position of the scrollContainer
      element.scrollLeft = (scrollWidth - clientWidth) / 2;
    } 
  };
```

This refAssignmentCallback should be passed to the ref attribute of your image container.

Below full snippet

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {

  const refAssignCallback = (ref) => {
    if (ref) {
      //the containerRef is currently null, ref available = mounted.
      var element = ref;
      var scrollWidth = element.scrollWidth;
      var clientWidth = element.getBoundingClientRect().width;

      //explicitly set the scrollTop position of the scrollContainer
      element.scrollLeft = (scrollWidth - clientWidth) / 2;
    } 
  }; 

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div name="container" ref={refAssignCallback} style={{overflowX: "auto"}}>
        <div style={{width: "4000px"}}>Image Placeholder Div</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-lederberg-nm94d)